# Разбиение на слагаемые

Tags: алгоритм

Необходимо получить все возможные разбиения целого неотрицательного числа на слагаемые с такими условиями:

1. Строго задается количество слагаемых, минимальное и максимальное возможные значения слагаемых
2. Разбиение представлено в виде отсортированного по убыванию списка целых чисел
3. Все возможные разбиения встречаются среди полученных **ровно один раз** (нет ни повторяющихся, ни потерянных)
4. Разбиения сами по себе могут быть получены в любом порядке

Например, число 5 разбивается на 4 слагаемых от 0 до 4 таким образом:

- (4, 1, 0, 0)
- (3, 2, 0, 0)
- (3, 1, 1, 0)
- (2, 2, 1, 0)
- (2, 1, 1, 1)

**Особую ценность** представляет решение, где исходя из первого условия и некоторого разбиения можно получить другое, следующее за ним в лексикографическом порядке.

Алгоритм планируется использовать на Java, в формате `Iterator<List<Integer>>`

Comment: Интересная тема для курсовой. А в чём вопрос?

Comment: @Oliver, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.
А вообще, как вариант, запилить рекурсию. Делаем оценки для первого слагаемого, и запускаем снова. Т.е. каждый проход -- +1 слагаемое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделано. Только формат `Iterator<int[]>`

```
public class SumVariantsProvider implements Iterator<int[]> {
private int[] next;
private final int min;

public SumVariantsProvider(int sum, int count, int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    if (sum > max * count || sum < min * count)
        next = null;
    else {
        next = new int[count];
        packToLeft(0, sum - min * count, max);
    }
}

private void packToLeft(int startIndex, int extra, int max) {
    for (int i = startIndex; i < next.length; ++i) {
        int thisExtra = Math.min(extra, max - min);
        next[i] = min + thisExtra;
        extra -= thisExtra;
    }
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return next != null;
}

public int[] next() {
    if (next == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    int[] result = next.clone();
    int indexToDecrease = next.length - 1;
    final int currentMin = next[indexToDecrease];
    int sum = 0;
    while (indexToDecrease >= 0 && next[indexToDecrease] - currentMin < 2)
        sum += next[indexToDecrease--] - min;
    if (indexToDecrease < 0)
        next = null;
    else
        packToLeft(indexToDecrease + 1, sum + 1, --next[indexToDecrease]);
    return result;
}

public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

}